# What is wrong with my JavaScript DOM code to print a simple text?

Tags: javascript

I have to print "Hello, Mars", but something is wrong. I've tried to add `paragraph.appendChild(text)` too but it not works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        const body = document.getElementById("body")
        const paragraph = document.createElement("p")
        const text = document.createTextNode("Hello, Mars")
        body.appendChild(paragraph)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `<body>` element does not have the id "body"; it has no id at all. Use `document.body` instead.

Comment: You also never do anything with `text`

Answer (score 1):

Two things here:

Firstly, you never add `text` to the created `paragraph`, which would be done by adding this:

```
paragraph.appendChild(text);
```

Secondly, using [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) you are selecting an item that would have `id="body"`, not the `<body>` element on your page. You can get the body using [document.body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/body) as follows:

```
const body = document.body;
```